# Repetition while copying data to SQL table from multiple sheets

Tags: sql, excel, talend

I have to copy data from multiple excel sheets to the single SQL table.

Excel inputs:
Sheet1's columns: fname a, b. lname c, d. (2 rows)
Sheet2's columns: city boston, austin, state ma, tx. (2 rows)

My output (tMSSqlOutpout) has 4 rows instead of 2.
a c boston ma, a c austin tx, b d boston ma, b d austin tx.

Desired output: a c boston ma, b d austin tx. (2 rows only)

How do I manage this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: are you doing lookup in tmap? if yes then what is joining condition there? can you put a screenshot of join condition.

Comment: The data specified in the question has no obvious join key. What links the first record of the person sheet to the first record of the city sheet other than that being the order they are in?

Comment: Yes that's the problem. They don't have any common column to do a join on.

Comment: No, I am not doing a lookup on tmap, I created earlier job named 'lookup'. That could be the reason for the connection to get named 'row2(Lookup)', I am not sure.

Comment: So is it possible with out any join condition? To do it only on based of the order of the entries.

Comment: It's possible but it's a really bad idea and you have to question why you are doing this in the first place. If you can't be certain of the relationship between these two datasets then how do you know that your resulting dataset will make any sense?

Comment: You are right, I need to think more about my database design. But for now may I know how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments, you don't have a natural key to join the two data sets. Instead you could generate a sequence for each data set that would increment equally for both data sets and would equate to being your row number on each data set.

First of all, this should set alarm bells ringing about the state of your data and how you can be sure that row n in one data set definitely corresponds to row n in another data set. It smacks of something being badly normalised out without proper keys being added and it can be very dangerous to assume that the resulting data set from this is going to be accurate.

If you absolutely must do this, however, then you should assign a `Numeric.sequence` to each of your data sets. You can do this in a tMap that precedes your joining tMap:

[image: Apply a sequence to the data set]

Notice the `"s1"` parameter to the `Numeric.sequence`. If you reuse this elsewhere then it will increment this one rather than starting from 1 so typically you would want to choose a unique name for each sequence you have in your job (although there are obviously occasions where incrementing a previously defined sequence is what you desire).

Once you have defined a unique sequence with the same starting numbers (the second parameter) and the same increment numbers (the third parameter) then you should be able to create a join on these instances:

[image: Then inner join on the sequences]